# Restrict nginx to one directory

Tags: nginx

I would like to restrict an nginx server to one directory, example/ in this case.  I would have presumed it's something like this but it doesn't work.

```
location ~ !(^/example) {
    return 403;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
  # other server directives

  deny all;

  location /example {
    allow all;
    # other location directives
  }
}
```